# Why Fisheye charts does not consider that files were deleted?

Tags: svn, charts, atlassian-fisheye

*Line chart* in Fisheye shows specific number of lines in project in defined folder for 27.11.2015. Number of files were deleted in 28.11.2015. But line of code metric is not changed in *Line chart*. Chart just shows in the bottom that files was changed. Deleted files had the *.form extention.

Why *Line chart* does not decrease the number of code lines after files were deleted?

Also if I open the Code Metrics tab, LOC by File Extension chart shows that folder has *.form files. But now there are no *.form files in that folder.

Why LOC by File Extension chart considers deleted files?

Defined folder located in trunk branch of SVN.

Here is the chart:
[image]

Comment: In SCM Details -> SVN Symbolic Rules -> And then Apply the Following Rules option None selected for the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I re-indexed the Line Count Data Index and it helped me. See [Re-indexing your repository](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/re-indexing-your-repository-298976884.html)